# Attach CCScene to EAGLView

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, eaglview

I am trying to attach my CCScene class to my EAGLView. So my EAGLView is an IBOutlet in Class 1. I connected it and settered and gettered it. Then in my ViewDidLoad in my Class 1 I do:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setOpenGLView:self.eaglView];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[CCSceneClass node]];
```

The problem is it is not calling the class that I show below in my CCScene class (I tested with NSLogs). Anyway lets say my CCScene class is named CCSceneClass, how would I properly connect it from my ViewDidLoad from Class1 (My UIViewController) so that this method in my CCScene class gets called?

Also this is some code that I do in this method if this matters at all:

```
-(id)initWithEaglView:(EAGLView*)view {
NSLog(@"initWithEAGLView");
        //Attach CCDirector to EAGLView
        director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
        [director setOpenGLView:view];
        //Make CCLayer and CCScene
        CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
        CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];
        [scene addChild:layer];
        [director runWithScene:scene];
        [director setDisplayFPS:NO];
}
```

Thanks!

**My Issue:**

**1.** What is the point of these 2 lines (btw the first line came up with a warning saying that, that method was not found:

```
[director setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink];
[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
```

I already have a game loop in my CCLayer class so does that mean I can just get rid of these lines?

That is the only question I have left!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not "connect" a CCScene class with the OpenGL view, and there's no need to really.

After you've set the eaglView you would proceed as normal to run your scene with CCDirector:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setOpenGLView:self.eaglView];
...
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[CCSceneClass node]];
```

If you need access to the eaglView inside your scene class, you get this via CCDirector:

```
EAGLView* view = [CCDirector sharedDirector].openglView;
```

**UPDATE:**

Full code to initialize Cocos2D view in a UIKit app:

```
CCDirector* director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink];
[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
[director setOpenGLView:(EAGLView*)subview];
[director runWithScene:[HelloWorldLayer scene]];
```

There's a chapter in my [Learn Cocos2D book](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/) explaining integration of Cocos2D in a UIKit app (and vice versa) in more detail. You can also download the [book's source code](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/files/Learn_Cocos2D_Game_Development_with_iOS5_Source_Code.zip) (2nd edition) from that page and look at the Chapter 15 example project "ViewBasedAppWithCocos2D".

Comment: Can you completely recheck my original post, it is not working properly!

Comment: Thanks! I see that my CCScene init method is now getting called but I have 2 issues which I will explain in my original post.